# error in logical function with booleans in C

Tags: c, function, boolean-logic

I am learning to program in C and I am trying to do a basic function to light a candle, which consists of 3 scenarios: the candle is lit, the candle is out and I have a lighter, the candle is off and I have no lighter

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdbool.h>

bool on=false;
bool lighter=false;

void candle(bool on,bool lighter){


    if(on==false && lighter=true){
        
        on=true;
        printf('The candle is out ,lit candle...');
        
    }
    else if(on==false && lighter=false){
        printf('The candle is out and I must look for a lighter');
        printf('I already have the lighter');
        lighter=true;
        printf('lit candle...');
        on=true;
    }

print('The candle is lit');
return 0;
}
```

the problem is that vscode gives me an error about the on variable, which says "expression must be a modifiable lvalue" and I don't understand how it works

Comment: You probably didn't want a single `=` in `lighter=true` in this line: `if(on==false && lighter=true){`  And the same with `lighter=false` in this line: `else if(on==false && lighter=false){`

Comment: Can you share your main function? Having a local and global variable named the same is bad practice.

Comment: Also, all your printf functions have strings wit hsingle quotes but they should be double quotes.

Comment: `=` is assignment, `==` is comparison. You're mixing the two in your `if` statements.

Comment: And `print('The candle is lit');` should be `printf` not `print`

Comment: And you are returning 0 from that function but the function is declared to return void so you can't return a value.

Comment: i fixed the = and the printf and change the return 0 to return; but doesnt work I get the following errors:

tempCodeRunnerFile.c:12:16: warning: character constant too long for its type
   12 |         printf('The candle is out ,lit candle...');

tempCodeRunnerFile.c:12:9: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Wformat-security]
   12 |         printf('The candle is out ,lit candle...');

/usr/include/stdio.h:332:43: note: expected ‘const char * restrict’ but argument is of type ‘int’
  332 | extern int printf (const char *__restrict __format, ...);

Comment: I'd be very surprised if warnings didn't catch the error. make sure to enable your compiler's warnings!!! I use `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` with `gcc`

Comment: Also, explicitly comparing to `true` and `false` is very weird. `!on && lighter` would suffice.

Comment: I don't really understand how it works, the truth is I did the same function in php, js and python following the same logic and I had no problems :(

Comment: Character constant is too long means you are using single quotes when you should be using double quotes.  the problem is that C is a very different language than script languages like javascript, php and python.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, there are several things wrong.

A couple of them are really minor typos:

- A string of characters has double quotes surrounding it, but the strings in your printf statements have single quotes.  So you need to change all of them to double quotes.
- The function you are using to print is `printf` but you accidentally use `print` for the last one.  So you need to change that last one to `printf`
- The `printf` function doesn't automatically put a newline at the end of the line.  So you need to either a newline to the end of each format string you pass to `printf` or use the `puts` function instead.
- A void function cannot return a value but you have declared the function to return void while still trying to return zero from the function.  So you need to delete the `return 0;` from that function or change the return type to `int`.

A couple of them are more serious:

- `==` is comparison for equality but `=` is assignment.  You probably don't want to assign values to variables in if statement conditions.  So you need to change all the `=` in your if statement conditions to `==`.
- C is pass-by-value, so When you pass variables to a function a *copy* of the variable is received by the function.  If you change the parameter in the function you are changing a *copy* of the variable passed to the function so your changes are never seen.  So, if you want the changes to be reflected, you need to use function parameters that are pointers to the original variables - or use global variables and no function parameters.
- You have global variables and function parameters with the same name.  They are not the same variable.  If you use the variable name in the function you are using the function parameter and not the global variable - the global variable is never changed.  So you should never have global variables and function parameters with the same name.

If you make all those changes your code will compile.

If you use global variables instead of function parameters your code would look like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdbool.h>

bool on=false;
bool lighter=false;

void candle(){

    if(on==false && lighter==true){
        
        on=true;
        printf("The candle is out ,lit candle...\n");
        
    }
    else if(on==false && lighter==false){
        printf("The candle is out and I must look for a lighter\n");
        printf("I already have the lighter\n");
        lighter=true;
        printf("lit candle...\n");
        on=true;
    }

    printf("The candle is lit\n");
}

int main(){
    candle();
    printf("Result: on=%s lighter=%s\n",
        (on?"true":"false"),
        (lighter?"true":"false")
    );
}
```

If you use function parameters that are pointers to the original variables your code would look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdbool.h>

void candle(bool * on, bool * lighter){

    if(*on==false && *lighter==true){
        
        *on=true;
        printf("The candle is out ,lit candle...\n");
        
    }
    else if(*on==false && *lighter==false){
        printf("The candle is out and I must look for a lighter\n");
        printf("I already have the lighter\n");
        *lighter=true;
        printf("lit candle...\n");
        *on=true;
    }

    printf("The candle is lit\n");
}

int main(){
    bool on=false;
    bool lighter=false;
    candle(& on, & lighter);
    printf("Result: on=%s lighter=%s\n",
        (on?"true":"false"),
        (lighter?"true":"false")
    );
}
```